# python3.4.2 how to assign a string with texts and variables

Tags: string, python-3.x, variable-assignment

I want to assign string in the format of two words followed by their corresponding variables like:

```
"newstring = 'length', length, 'slope', slope"
```

And I will use this in a text function like `text = Text(point1, newstring)`
is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [format](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#format):

```
>>> length=22
>>> slope=45
>>> newstring='length {}, slope {}'.format(length, slope)
>>> newstring
'length 22, slope 45'
```

The format function or format method have a rich set of [format specifications](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#formatspec) allowing strings to be presented in the desired way:

```
>>> 'Feeling hexey 0x{:X} and octally 0{:o} for decimal {}'.format(12, 12, 12)
'Feeling hexey 0xC and octally 014 for decimal 12'
>>> "Lot's o decimals: {:0.30f}".format(.5)
"Lot's o decimals: 0.500000000000000000000000000000"
```

You can also concatenate like string types together:

```
>>> 'length ' + str(length) + ' slope ' + str(slope)
'length 22 slope 45'
```

Or use the older 'meatball' operator:

```
>>> 'length %d, slope %d' % (length, slope)
'length 22, slope 45'
```

But those are not as elegant as `format`...

Comment: thank you so much! how can i let python display only to 2 or 3 decimal points? because my length and slope values are all decimals and it will look better if i let python only display to a certain number of decimal points!

Comment: Read the documentation on format specifiers. It will be something like `'length {:.2f}, slope {:.2f}'.format(length, slope)` for 2 decimals.